# Read xml files from assembly

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, .net-assembly

I'm trying to read xml files from assembly, this is my code:

```
private Assembly testAssembly;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string testfile = "stack.xml";
        String testfileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", testAssembly.GetName().Name, testfile);

        using (Stream stream = testAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(testfileName))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var value = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("The read file is {0}", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've got a problem on this line:

```
String testfileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", testAssembly.GetName().Name, 
                                     testfile);
```

Null ref exception unhandled, it says null. Any help???
    [image]

Comment: How do you obtain the assembly reference passed to `Form1`?

Comment: Did you check you `testAssembly` is null or not??

Comment: I have updated my question, testAssembly is not null, i can see the xml file name. My xml file is in the same project and it's embede.

Comment: @linguini - I would argue that testAssembly is `null` based on the `NullReferenceException` within the screenshot you posted.

Comment: show the screen in the exactly same situation, but with the mouse over `testAssembly`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `marksAssembly` is `null`

Comment: @linguini - Make sure its not `null`

Comment: @Ramhound: How can i do this??

Comment: when the exception is throw, put the mouse over `testAssembly` it shoudl show you a little tooltip in which you can read if `testAssebmly` is `null` or not

Comment: Yes, it says testAssembly is null. What should i do exactly??

Comment: @Quick Joe Smith: What should i assign, the filename or something??

Comment: You have to load the assembly! Check one of this [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx)

Comment: @ NaNNy: Could u please tell me what should i load and where??

Comment: If the assembly that you want to load is in the reference of the project, you just need this in the click handler: `testAssembly = Assembly.Load("nameOfAssemblyWithoutTheExtension");`. If is not in the reference you can specify the path with `Assembly.LoadFile("PathOfYourAssembly")`. You can found an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34301/Assembly-LoadFile-versus-Assembly-LoadFrom-NET-obs)

Comment: I got one project and I have loaded the xml file in the same project embeded it and there is no other assembly.

Comment: I really don't understand why you need to use `Assembly` when you have the xml loaded (and included) in your project...
Check this two question: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416564/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-projects-root-directory) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580526/get-file-path-for-file-included-in-project).

Answer (score 1):

```
string resName = "resources/HistoryConnections.xml";  

private static UnmanagedMemoryStream GetResourceStream(string resName)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var strResources = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
            var rStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(strResources);
            var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(rStream);
            var items = resourceReader.OfType<DictionaryEntry>();
            var stream = items.First(x => (x.Key as string) == resName.ToLower()).Value;
            return (UnmanagedMemoryStream)stream;
        }
```